# Убрать сообщения об ошибках

Tags: golang

Приложение под Windows компилируется нормально, и работает, если нет проблем. Но например, отключаю SQL сервер, и приложение начинает сыпать в консоль:

> goroutine 5 [chan receive]:
>
> database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc0820500b0)
>           C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:727 +0x4c
>
> created by database/sql.Open
>           C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:493 +0x346

Хотя использую logrus и все ошибки пишу в файл лога, но почему-то туда именно это ничего не попадает. Возможно как-то это перехватить и подавить вывод на экран?

Comment: Вы пишете в logrus. А куда пишет функционал пакета для работы с SQL сервером? Вообще, что за пакет? Надо посмотреть какой логер он использует и настроить его.

Comment: Использую github.com/lib/pq
Ок, спс, покапаю.

Comment: @MaLS
С этим разобрался, проблема немного в другом была, просто отдавало на другое :))
Вопрос на ваш ответ. А как можно привязать текущий логгер к другим используемым пакетам, ну например вот использую https://github.com/labstack/echo , там есть echo.SetLogger(), но как в него впихнуть логгер параметром? Logrus я использую через: import log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"

Comment: В GO с такой необходимостью не сталкивался. В .NET (практика показала) когда начинаешь собирать множество компонентов, которые используют различные логеры приходится использовать адаптеры. Эти адаптеры перехватывают процесс записи одного логера и пишут в другой.

Comment: @Darkman в logrus можно получить указатель на стандартный логгер. `logger := logrus.StandardLogger()`, a уже потом `logger` передавать в `echo.SetLogger()`